# Bootstrap 4 collapse expands div width when toggled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a form in bootstrap using tag helpers. but, I have a collapse section and when the user toggles the collapse the width of the form will resize giving some ugly UX. I am not sure why the width changes when the user expands or collapses.

Here is the example for this issue. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/domshyra/pen/pVBbEp?editors=1100)

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
<form action="/UpdateHeader" method="post">
  <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="p-4 mt-sm-4 mb-sm-4 border border-light" style="border-width: .2rem !important"> 

        <!--Project and Sub Project-->
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="ProjectName">Project</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ProjectName" name="ProjectName" value="Foo">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="SubProjectName">Sub Project</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SubProjectName" name="SubProjectName" value="Bar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Building GSF, Currency, and Estimate Date-->
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="BuildingGSF">Building GSF</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Building GSF must be a number." data-val-required="The Building GSF field is required." id="BuildingGSF" name="BuildingGSF" value="3570.00">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="Currency">Currency</label>
            <select class="form-control" required data-val="true" data-val-required="The CurrencyID field is required." id="Currency_CurrencyID" name="Currency.CurrencyID">
              <option value="Dollar" selected>Default</option>
              <option selected="selected" value="1">Dollar</option>
              <option value="2">Yen</option>
              <option value="3">Euro</option>
              <option value="4">Peso</option>
              <option value="5">Pound</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="EstimateDate">Estimate Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Estimate Date field is required." id="EstimateDate" name="EstimateDate" value="01/01/0001">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Accuracy Range and Estimate Class-->
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
            <label>Accuracy Range</label>
            <div class="row">
              <label class="col-lg-1 col-form-label d-none d-lg-block text-nowrap text-right">Low</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text">-</span> </div>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Cost Range Low (%) must be a number." data-val-required="The Cost Range Low (%) field is required." id="CostPercentRangeLow" name="CostPercentRangeLow" placeholder="Cost Range Low (%)"
                            value="0.05">
                  <div class="invalid-feedback"> Percent range low is required. </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <label class="col-lg-1 col-form-label d-none d-lg-block text-nowrap text-right">High</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text">+</span> </div>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Cost Range High (%) must be a number." data-val-required="The Cost Range High (%) field is required." id="CostPercentRangeHigh" name="CostPercentRangeHigh" placeholder="Cost Range High (%)"
                            value="0.20">
                  <div class="invalid-feedback"> Percent range high is required. </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="EstimateClass">Estimate Class</label>
            <select class="form-control" required data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="EstimateClass_ID" name="EstimateClass.ID">
              <option value="Class 2" selected>Default</option>
              <option selected="selected" value="22">Class 2</option>
              <option value="23">Class 3</option>
              <option value="25">Class 1</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Unit cost and qty-->
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="ProjectTypeMetricID">Unit Cost</label>
            <select class="form-control" required data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ProjectTypeMetricID_ID" name="ProjectTypeMetricID.ID">
              <option value="Cost Per Seat" selected>Default</option>
              <option value="26">Cost Per Key</option>
              <option value="27">Cost Per Bed</option>
              <option selected="selected" value="28">Cost Per Seat</option>
              <option value="29">Cost Per Workstation</option>
              <option value="30">Cost Per KWh Used</option>
              <option value="31">Cost Per KWh Generated</option>
              <option value="32">N/A</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="MetricQty">Quantity</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." id="MetricQty" name="MetricQty" value="1000.00">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Project desc-->
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="ProjectDesc">Project Description</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="3" id="ProjectDesc" name="ProjectDesc" placeholder="Enter a project description">
    Test desc</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="optional-fields mb-2 border-bottom"> <a class="font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" href="#optional-fields" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="optional-fields"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right pb-1"></i> Optional fields </a> </div>
        <div class="collapse show mt-2 mb-2 border-bottom" id="optional-fields"> 

          <!--Location data-->
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="Region">Region</label>
              <select class="form-control" required data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Region_ID" name="Region.ID">
                <option value="Default" selected>Default</option>
                <option value="4">Nothrwest USA</option>
                <option value="5">Southwest USA</option>
                <option value="6">United Kingdom</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="ProjectCountry">Country</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ProjectCountry" name="ProjectCountry" placeholder="Country" value="">
              <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please provide a valid country. </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="ProjectState">State</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ProjectState" name="ProjectState" placeholder="State" value="">
              <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please provide a valid state. </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="ProjectCity">City</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ProjectCity" name="ProjectCity" placeholder="City" value="">
              <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please provide a valid city. </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--Who data-->
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="PointOfContact">Point of Contact</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PointOfContact" name="PointOfContact" placeholder="John Doe" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="OtherPointOfContact">Secondary Point of Contact</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="OtherPointOfContact" name="OtherPointOfContact" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="SubmitForm" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remember that questions should be helpful to future readers. Please post the relevant code in the question instead of linking to external sites that may change over time.

Comment: good call. Added the html. thx

Comment: you will need to define width of your main container. add `.container` class in this line. `<div class="container p-4 mt-sm-4 mb-sm-4 border border-light" style="border-width: .2rem !important">`

Comment: wow amazing. thanks! what is the logic behind that? I have a container-fluid defined above. why does that need to be a container as well?